# Правильно ли решение?

Tags: python

я новичок, решаю задачи Эйлера используя ЯП python, и на пятой мой мозг выдал такое решение:

```
count = 0
for i in range(1, 21):
    while not count%i == 0:
        count + 1
print(count)
```

но код не выполняется, ошибок нету, но похоже решение слишком медленное, так вот мне интересно, при высокой производительности, этот код будет верным. И также у меня вопрос, в цикле while, правильно ли я сделал, что написал оператор not.

Напомню, условие задачи:

2520 - самое маленькое число, которое делится без остатка на все числа от 1 до 10.

Какое самое маленькое число делится нацело на все числа от 1 до 20?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, это был мой первый вопрос, я уже скорректировал его

Comment: Задачи Эйлера нужно решать не перебором, а в первую очередь головой. Первый десяток ещё можно решить сплошным перебором, но потом уже нет.

Comment: @markkulikov С чего вы взяли, что код не выполняется? Код выполняется.

Comment: Подсказка - чтобы получить число, которое делится на все числа от 1 до 20 можно, например, перемножить все числа от 1 до 20. Хотя это будет не самое маленькое такое число, но вы можете подумать, как получить из него число поменьше.

Comment: Кажется приведенный код должен работать мгновенно и выдавать ноль. В каком-то смысле это почти верный ответ. Остаток от деления нуля на что угодно будет ноль 

Comment: Решение задачи "влоб" должно было бы содержать цикл в цикле, а не одиночный цикл. )

Answer (score 0):

Как то так. Но я сам тоже новичок)

```
count = 20
arr = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
def check(v):
    for i in arr:
        if v%i != 0:
            return False
    return True
while count:
    print(count)
    if check(count) == False:
        count+=20
        continue
    else:
        print(count)
        break
```

=232792560 но не факт что ближнее=)
А ещё в теории можно начать счетчик с 2520 и увеличивать ровно на столько же, 5040 и т.д.

Comment: i это делитель, а не  число. А делители и нужны до 20.

Comment: Не нужно определять функцию в цикле. Это обычно делается перед основным кодом. False пишется с заглавной буквы, и цикл  while count ни разу не выполнится, потому что count равно 0

Comment: С телефона сижу. Код не тестил. В теории сейчас должен работать.

Comment: Кроме того, инкрементировать по 1 - безумная трата времени и ресурсов. Очевидно, что если число делится на все числа от 2 до 20, то оно как минимум чётное. Т.е. начинать надо с чётного числа и увеличивать на 2. Это вдвое сократит перебор. А если чуток подумать, то можно сократить ещё в несколько раз.

Comment: Все просто задушили.))

Comment: Жду еще камни) но уже утром)